# Удалить элементы равные min

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Math.random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите количество элементов:");
        int n=input.nextInt();
        int []D=new int[n];
        int i;
        int Indexmin,min=0;
        for(i=0;i<D.length;i++){
            D[i]=(int)(random()*10);
            System.out.print(D[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        Indexmin=0;
        for(i=1;i<D.length;i++){
            if(D[Indexmin]>D[i])
                Indexmin=i;
            min=D[Indexmin];
        }
        if (D[i]=min)
            D.splice(Indexmin, 1);

        System.out.print("min="+min);
        for(i=0;i<D.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(D[i] + " ");

        } }
}
```

Компилятор выдает следующие ошибки:

```
Error:(27, 17) java: incompatible types
  required: boolean
  found:    int


Error:(28, 14) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method splice(int,int)   location: variable D of type int[]
```

Почему не распознает `splice`?

Comment: Почему не распознает splice?

Comment: Это же java, а не javascript, нельзя просто так взять и удалить элемент из массива. Создайте массив на одну ячейку короче, и вызовите пару раз `System.arrayCopy`, или вместо массива используйте класс `ArrayList`, у него есть `remove(int index)` и `sublist(from, to).clear();`. Или просто при выводе пропустите.

Comment: А вы можете подправить мой код,а то я вас не очень понимаю.Я новичок

Answer (score 1):

В Java нельзя удалять элементы из массива, можно лишь скопировать элементы в новый массив (без лишнего элемента), например, воспользовавшись операцией `System.arraycopy` Но если вам всё-таки вам нужен функционал с удалением элементов то используйте коллекцию `ArrayList`, в там есть метод `.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `int []D=new int[n];`
сделать `ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<>()` - это тот же массив, только без заморочек с задаванием размерности при объявлении. 
Чтобы добавить элемент нужно будет сделать `d.add(сюда ложим Integer)` .
Чтобы удалить по индексу `d.remove(индекс)`, но внутри цикла так делать нельзя, потому что размер этого массива считывается перед заходом в цикл и не пересчитывается, и если удалишь элемент кинет IndexOutOfBoundException при проходе цикла.